# mysql ,"load data in file" , wrong file path

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to  upload the contents of a text file using this:

```
  myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys", "root", "*****8");

        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        String sql="LOAD DATA INFILE"+ "'C:\\Users\\willf\\Documents\\comps sci\\NEA\\V1.4\\map files\\map.txt'"+"INTO TABLE sys.mazes";


        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

"java.sql.SQLException: File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\UserswillfDocumentscomps sciNEAV1.4map filesmap.txt' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)"

As you can see the filepath is completely different to what i'm giving it.

Comment: Remove the two quotes `'`. Use `"C:\\Users\\willf\\Documents\\comps sci\\NEA\\V1.4\\map files\\map.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is looking for a relative path using forward slashes. Try this instead: `"'/C:/Users/willf/Documents/comps sci/NEA/V1.4/map files/map.txt'"`

Comment: thanks ,file path seems to be right now ,but says can't find file with error "OS errno 13 - Permission denied"

Comment: @Fred As far as I know, `LOAD DATE INFILE` is executed by the MySQL server process, which is run by a user that doesn't have access to your user folder.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried using LOCAL aswell but its not supported in my sql version apparently.

Comment: whats the recommened way of uploading the contents of a txt file ?

Comment: @Fred Depends on the type of file. If it's a SQL file, the recommended way is just to read it in via the command line. For a CSV, there are multiple approaches, none bad. Best way would probably be to just write a Java program that parses it and updates the table row by row.